# What is the derivative of $x^TAx$ respect to matrix $A$ where $x$ is a vector

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

What is the derivative of $x^TAx$ respect to matrix $A$ where $x$ is a vector? Isn't it $xx$?

Below is what I calculate, please help me to check where the problem is:

$\frac{d}{dA}x^TAx=\frac{dx^TA}{dA}x+x^TA\frac{dx}{dA}=\frac{dx^TA}{dA}x=xx$.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Derivative is a function, not a value, at which point do you want to compute it?

Comment: I didn't have the point. What I have is I want to calculate the derivate of $x^TAx$ respect to the element between x^T and x (which is matrix A here and it can be changed to \beta in some cases).

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a_{i,j}} (x^\top A x) = \frac{\partial}{\partial a_{i,j}} \sum_{i'=1}^n \sum_{j'=1}^n a_{i', j'}x_{i'} x_{j'} = x_i x_j,$$
so if you put all the partial derivatives into a matrix whose $i,j$ entry is $x_ix_j$, you obtain $xx^\top$.

Comment: One more question: I think there is a chain rule for matrix derivative and so I used chain rule in the calculation I showed in the question. But the final result is not what I want. Do you know what mistake I made in that calculation?